# Return a dynamic unknown type

Tags: c#, selenium, generics, selenium-webdriver

As part of using page object pattern,  I have a method that should `return` the a class when clicking a button. 
The thing is that I have several buttons in a list which each one of them returns a different page, therefore a different class.
I have tried using the following but getting an error.

```
  public dynamic ClickTheMenuButtonWorkplace<T>(string ElementID, T ClassToReturn)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        var MenuButton = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id(ElementID)));
        MenuButton.Click();

        return ClassToReturn;
    }
```

The `T` actually represents the class is being returned , according to the button clicked.

An example of using this method is :

```
Lakochot IDDetails = new SargelElyon(_webdriver).ClickTheMenuInabWorkplace("nav_conts", new Lakochot(_webdriver));
IDDetails.foo();
```

The `LoginPgae` currently have only a constructor that initializing the `webdriver` and has a `foo` method that printing something.

I'm getting an error says:
`Missing compiler required member Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert`

Maybe there is a better way doing that anyway..?

Comment: Why do you not want to return `T`?

Comment: sorry. do you suggest to return T?

Comment: You wrote "The `T` actually represents the class is being returned", so it seems like that's what you want, yes.

Comment: might be. I'll try that and let you know.10X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case why not return `T`?

> The `T` actually represents the class is being returned, according to the button clicked.

makes it look like this is exactly what you want.

```
public T ClickTheMenuButtonWorkplace<T>(string ElementID, T ClassToReturn)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    var MenuButton = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id(ElementID)));
    MenuButton.Click();

    return ClassToReturn;
}

...

var IDDetails = new SargelElyon(_webdriver)
        .ClickTheMenuButtonWorkplace("nav_conts", new Lakochot(_webdriver));
// ^ is a Lakochot
IDDetails.foo();
```

If you want to use `dynamic`, which you likely do not need here, see [Tom Coldenhoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47246797/7366707).